# flywaydb baseline baselineVersion parameter is being ignored

Tags: flyway

I am trying to impelment flywaydb in our process. In our env each client has their own instance of the DB.

I have a bash that loops through the clients to run migrate. So the command looks like

```
flyway -url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1434/main_client_$ID migrate
```

This all works when all the clients start from the baseline. But as we add new customers their DB will reflect the newest code. Now we have older clients started with V1(and all the migration scripts to V2) and new clients with the latest DB V2.

I thought i could do something like :::

```
flyway baseline -url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1434/main_client_3 
                --baselineVersion=2 --baselineDescription="Base 2 version"
```

but when i do it this way then call info i see something like :

```
 +---------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------+
 | Version | Description           | Installed on        | State   |
 +---------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------+
 | 1       | << Flyway Baseline >> | 2015-06-08 22:07:54 | Success |
 | 1.1     | update                |                     | Pending |
 | 1.2.0   | update                |                     | Pending |
 | 1.2.1   | update                |                     | Pending |
 +---------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

if i look in the DB i see the version value of schema_version set to 1.

if via the DB i force schema_version column value to 1.2.0 i see

```
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------+
| Version | Description           | Installed on        | State   |
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 1       | Base version initial  |                     | <Baseln |
| 1.1     | update                |                     | <Baseln |
| 1.2.0   | << Flyway Baseline >> | 2015-06-08 22:07:54 | Success |
| 1.2.1   | update                |                     | Pending |
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

This is what i want. 
But i can not figure out how to set the value via the baseline command

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All parameters should be passed in with - not --

Comment: Thank you, BTW the command given in the doc. @ http://flywaydb.org/documentation/existing.html  ---  
flyway baseline -Dflyway.baselineVersion=1 -Dflyway.baselineDescription="Base version" does not work

Comment: How so? What do you mean exactly?